# british citizenship is it automatic.Or do i have to apply

Tags: canadian-citizens, uk-citizenship

I was born in the UK in 1937 and emigrated to Canada in 1967. Do I automatically have British citizenship or do I have to apply? I presently have a Canadian passport.

Comment: According to [this app](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen), almost certainly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't lose British citizenship upon naturalization in a foreign country after 1948. Since you naturalized in Canada after 1948, you did not lose British citizenship, and still have it.